# Is it possible to use unwind segues in WatchKit?

Tags: storyboard, segue, watchkit

I'm looking to have a WKInterfaceController unwind to the previous after a button is pressed.  [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) technical note from Apple is not updated for WatchKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After developing extensively with WatchKit, I can tell you they aren't. WatchKit doesn't use a traditional navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks @bgilham. Upon further investigation, all I needed was '[self popController];'